# Using route() function in laravel notification returns appname.test instead of 127.0.0.1:800

Tags: laravel, notifications

I am using route() function inside the notification file to send mail. But in mail, the route shows http://appname.test/aaaa... instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/aaa..
Whereas route() method in another part of controller works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `.env` file

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1/
```

to

```
APP_URL=http://appname.test/
```

don't forget to restart your server.
if still no working, try to clear your application cache and restart.